# python find a double quoted specific string

Tags: python, find

I have a block of HTML and I want to do the following.

```
if html.find('pid":"') != -1:
  # do something
```

and it always returns `-1`.
BUT `'pid":'`  (only one dbl quote works, but finds the wrong tag)

Comment: Post your HTML. Are you sure there isn't a whitespace or a newline after the `:`?

Comment: Please provide an example with code and example data and say what you expected - the only thing that's clear from your description is that you tried something and it didn't work as you expected, but it's not clear what the value of `html` was at the time and your final remark is entirely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was looking at the request.content, but searching on the request.text.  And the text I was looking for was eliminated in the request.text version.